# GMAIL: How to open a existing email in new window if I know its id?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, gmail-api

**Shortly: How to open email in gmail if I know its id in new window?**

Greetings. I get from GMAIL API the id of needed email. I want it to open in separate window by, for example, btn click in my add-on.
What I know:

- what using javascript code -`window.location.href =` to open url in new window.
- You can open drafts using URL `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=NeededID` but it wont work with for example `Sent` emails

Any idea how the url should look like so that you can open the email in separate window in gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total recall. Solution was found. The solution can be applied to open email in any folder not only in Sent folder.
To Open email in new window need its `id` and `thread_id` of that email.
Also known as `messageId` and `conversationId`.
By example messageId looks like this-  `msg-a:r8357142279172082424`
and thread id looks like this - `thread-a:r-7561979775658404696`

So here is javascript code with URL to open existing email in new window.

```js
  const message = encodeURIComponent(`#${conversationId}|${messageId}`);
  const url = `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/${message}`;
  const windowHeight = '540';
  const windowWidth = '960';
  window.open(url, '_blank', `location=yes,height=${windowHeight},width=${windowWidth},scrollbars=yes,status=yes`);
```

the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4dwU.png)
[image: already existing email is opened by gmail]

Answer (score 0):

I use this link to open the editable email ready to send:
"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all?compose="+ (ID EMAIL)

Here is an example that I use in the code in Google App Script.

```js
//Abrir rascunho no email
  let assuntoAProcurar = subject;
  let lista = GmailApp.search(assuntoAProcurar);
  let rascunho = GmailApp.getDrafts()
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (rascunho[i].getMessage().getSubject() == assuntoAProcurar) { 
        Logger.log("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose="+rascunho[i].getMessage().getThread().getId());
        return
    }
   }
```