# How to open specific email without whole thread in GMAIL?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

I need to open in new window desired email. I found the solution [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71936238/11135590) how to open desired email by URL, but have problem. If someone replied to that email it shows not only desired email but also whole thread.
I know of that desired email `threadId` and `messageId`.
Example of code

```
const message = encodeURIComponent(`#${conversationId}|${messageId}`);
  const url = `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/${message}`;
  const windowHeight = '540';
  const windowWidth = '960';
  window.open(url, '_blank', `location=yes,height=${windowHeight},width=${windowWidth},scrollbars=yes,status=yes`);
```

How looks like the problem if someone replied to desired email.
[image: message thread]

Any ideas How to open exatly desired email? For example by URL?

Comment: Have you found a way to do it using the GUI? If that functionality is not available in the GUI I don’t think you’ll be able to script it.

Comment: One thing to try would be turning off message threading and open a message to see what the URL is for an individual message. Then turn threading back on and see if the URL still works.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for me... I turned off Conversation View for my email, opened a sent email, copied the URL, turned Conversation View back on and then pasted the URL but it showed the sent message in the context of the thread. Is leaving conversation view turned off an option?

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for your attention to this question. 1) I do not found a way to exactly open in GUI desired email 2) " Is leaving conversation view turned off an option?" No because this functional(to open desired email in separate window) will be implemented to gmail extension so I as dev could not force user of my extension to turn off thread option at any means...

Comment: @Matthew I will then ask in GMAIL support about this . But probably in this time and space moment you can not do that. Sad(